Externalize large payloads using SMT transform in Kafka Connect
Several blogs mention Kafka Connect users externalizing large payloads using SMTs to implement the claim-check pattern:

https://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2020/08/07/apache-kafka-handling-large-messages-and-files-for-image-video-audio-processing/
https://www.morling.dev/blog/single-message-transforms-swiss-army-knife-of-kafka-connect/

However, I haven't yet found a specific example of this pattern in action. Does anyone have a good reference or experience using an SMT to implement the claim-check pattern?
For context, I'm using Azure Blob Storage and Azure Event Hub. The idea is to route large message payloads to Azure Blob Storage, while the original Kafka message would carry metadata (such as a URL pointing to the payload) and be sent to Event Hub.
The source connector would then need an SMT that reads the message from Event Hub, retrieves the payload from Azure Blob Storage, and processes it accordingly.

What specific issues are you having writing this on your own? Or having ChatGPT generate a starting point?

I'm wondering what the best approach would be. If I have a MongoDB source connector, would I embed a Azure Blob client within the custom SMT to send the payload?

You can. What issues are you having with this. Don't worry about "best", just get a working solution as a proof of concept.
